# Apache POI insert image

Tags: java, android, image, excel, apache-poi

I am having troubles with inserting a picture in an excel sheet im making.
There are a lot of question about this subject, but I simply cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.
My code runs, shows no errors but I do not see an image inserted :(

here is  the code:

```
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("nasuto_tlo.png");
    byte [] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is); 
    int pictureIndex = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
    is.close();

    CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    Drawing drawingPatriarch = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

    anchor.setCol1(2);
    anchor.setRow1(3);
    Picture pict = drawingPatriarch.createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex);
    pict.resize();

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(root+"/Busotina/Busotina1.xls");
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: POI has had problems inserting pictures in Word documents so I would think that this is related.

Comment: Does it work on a new sheet? POI can only add images to a sheet without any existing ones, it won't work if you try to add them to a sheet which already has some on it

Answer (score 29, accepted):

the problem is that your anchor is not correct.
You need to set all 4 values, because the default ones are 0 - but your first column can not be more right than your second one ;) You'll get negative extent.
You should get a warning when you open the excel file that it is corrupt.

So try

```
anchor.setCol1(2);
anchor.setCol2(3);
anchor.setRow1(3);
anchor.setRow2(4);
```

---

A working example from some code I wrote:

```
// read the image to the stream
final FileInputStream stream =
        new FileInputStream( imagePath );
final CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
final Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

final ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
anchor.setAnchorType( ClientAnchor.MOVE_AND_RESIZE );


final int pictureIndex =
        workbook.addPicture(IOUtils.toByteArray(stream), Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);


anchor.setCol1( 0 );
anchor.setRow1( LOGO_ROW ); // same row is okay
anchor.setRow2( LOGO_ROW );
anchor.setCol2( 1 );
final Picture pict = drawing.createPicture( anchor, pictureIndex );
pict.resize();
```

Comment: Hi! I need to insert image not from disk. My image stored in memory in Bitmap array and i dont want to save it on harddrive. Can I insert data from Bitmap array directly to .docx file?

Comment: Sorry, never worked with docx. But why not? AFAIK poi wants inputstreams and you could use a bytearrayinputstrean